# Insert NSMutableArray data into Dictionary with one key and multiple types of values

Tags: ios, swift3

I have my database stored in NSMutableArray and I want to insert it into Dictionary.

My database have three columns (name, detail, time) and I want it in Dictionary of type:

```
[String: ([String],[String],[String])]
```

e.g

```
[firstLetterOfName: ([name],[detail],[time])]
```

I need the Dictionary to add alphabetic sections into my TableView.

Can it be done? and how?
If I use struct how can I insert my data into the struct?

Comment: Consider to use a custom struct or class instead of a tuple as model. It makes things much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a struct and then create a dictionary using it.

```
struct Name {
    var name: String?
    var detail: String?
    var timestamp: Double?
}

let dictionary = ["summer": Name(name: "Summer", detail: "of", timestamp: 69)]
```